# Loop does not find user input String in List if there are more than one elements (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, substring, java.util.scanner

I am counting the occurrences of specified substrings in my LinkedList. If I enter one object, the method will recognize the String entered by the user and print the counts, however, if there are two elements in the List, it will only recognize the 2nd, and not the 1st.

For testing, I entered Dandelion, and then Rose. The program does not recognize the first element if the user enters it to analyze. For example:

Console output:

```
    Enter the plant name you wish to analyze: 
    Dandelion
    You must enter a valid plant name.

    Please try again: 
    Rose
    Analysis of 'Rose'

    'e' - 1 | 'o' - 1 | 'er' - 0 | 'ar' - 0
```

What am I missing in the loop structure?

If I change the while loop to an if statement, it recognizes both Dandelion and Rose (or any two names), but I have to type them both twice, like so:

```
    Enter the plant name you wish to analyze: 
    Dandelion
    You must enter a valid plant name.

    Please try again: 
    Dandelion
    Analysis of 'Dandelion'

    'e' - 1 | 'o' - 1 | 'er' - 0 | 'ar' - 0 //found the second try
```

Same for "Rose"

```
    Enter the plant name you wish to analyze: 
    Rose
    You must enter a valid plant name.

    Please try again: 
    Rose
    Analysis of 'Rose'

    'e' - 1 | 'o' - 1 | 'er' - 0 | 'ar' - 0 //again, only recognizes 2nd try
```

Here is the method:

```
    private void analyzePlantName(LinkedList<Plant> plantLinkedList) {

        int countLetterE = 0; //initialize counters
        int countLetterO = 0;
        int countLetterER = 0;
        int countLetterAR = 0;

        System.out.println("Analysis will be for substrings 'e', 'o', 'er', and 'ar'.\n");
        System.out.println("Enter the plant name you wish to analyze: ");
        String analysisString = input.next().trim(); //first try to input

        for(Plant plant : plantLinkedList) {
            if(!plant.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(analysisString)) { //this is supposed to search through the List for valid plant name. It only works if there's one plant.
                System.out.println("You must enter a valid plant name.\n");
                System.out.print("Please try again: ");
                System.out.println();
                analysisString = input.next().trim(); //re-initialize input string to try again.
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < analysisString.length(); i ++) { //all of this works fine with only one element in List

            if(analysisString.charAt(i) == e) {
                countLetterE = countLetterE + 1;
            }
            if(analysisString.charAt(i) == o) {
                countLetterO = countLetterO + 1;
            }
            if(analysisString.contains(er)) {
                countLetterER = countLetterER + 1;
            }
            if(analysisString.contains(ar)) {
                countLetterAR = countLetterAR + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Analysis of '" + analysisString + "'\n");

        System.out.println("'e' - " + countLetterE + " | 'o' - " + countLetterO + " | 'er' - " + countLetterER + " | 'ar' - " + countLetterAR + "\n"); //this all works fine.
    }
```

Comment: You are producing an error if the word doesn't match all the words in the list.  Most likely you intended to only produce an error if it doesn't match any words in the list.

Comment: Correct. Everything worked great, but then realized I should probably validate input. Both elements are in the List at the time of calling the analysis method, but for some reason one is getting passed over.

Comment: The way you have written the code is you report an error if the first word doesn't match.  You need to change the code so that it reports an error if none of them match ie only after the loop.

Comment: I see. Attempting that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** I made a mistake in my code. I ran some final tests and discovered that it was not counting substrings correctly. It would count single chars ('e' and 'o') just fine, but "er" and "ar" were not getting counted.

I explored the JavaDocs and ran across Boundary Matchers. Wow, powerful tool!

Here is my completed method, with working code.

Final note: Regex rocks. Just saying. :-)

```
    private void analyzePlantName(LinkedList<Plant> plantLinkedList) {

        /*
        This method will take a String as user input, loop through the LinkedList, and (if it exists in the List) display the counts of the specified substrings.
        If the String is not found, it will display an ERROR message and recursively call the method again.
         */

        System.out.println("Analysis for substrings 'e', 'o', 'er', and 'ar'.\n"); //Let's the user know which substrings are being searched/counted.
        System.out.println("Enter the plant name you wish to analyze: ");
        String analysisString = input.next().trim(); //first try to input
        analysisString = analysisString.toLowerCase();

        int countLetterE = 0; //initialize counters
        int countLetterO = 0;
        int countLetterER = 0;
        int countLetterAR = 0;
        Pattern patternER = Pattern.compile("\\Ber\\B"); //create non-word boundary for substring "er"
        Pattern patternAR = Pattern.compile("\\Bar\\B"); //create non-word boundary for substring "ar"
        Matcher matchER = patternER.matcher(analysisString);
        Matcher matchAR = patternAR.matcher(analysisString);

        boolean validInput = false; //initialize boolean variable

        for (int i = 0; i < plantLinkedList.size(); i++) {
            if (plantLinkedList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(analysisString)) { //loop through List to match user String with plant name
                validInput = true; //if found, break out of loop
                break;
            }
        }
        if (validInput) { //if conditions are met, count substrings and display

            while(matchER.find()) { //loop through analysisString and increment each time pattern "er" is found
                countLetterER++;
            }
            while(matchAR.find()) { //loop through analysisString and increment each time pattern "ar" is found
                countLetterAR++;
            }
            /*
            Separate loop for single chars
             */
            for (int i = 0; i < analysisString.length(); i++) { 
                if (analysisString.charAt(i) == 'e') {
                    countLetterE++;
                }
                if (analysisString.charAt(i) == 'o') {
                    countLetterO++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Analysis of '" + analysisString + "'\n");

            System.out.println("'e' - " + countLetterE + " | 'o' - " + countLetterO + " | 'er' - " + countLetterER + " | 'ar' - " + countLetterAR + "\n"); //this all works fine.
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR. You must enter a valid plant name.\n");
            System.out.print("Please try again.\n");
            analyzePlantName(plantLinkedList); //recursive method call
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting input:

```
String analysisString = input.next().trim(); //first try to input
```

and expect it to match the first element of your method linked-list argument 'plantLinkedList'.
and if it doesn't you get another input:

```
if(!plant.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(analysisString)) {
...
     analysisString = input.next().trim();    
}
```

I think what you meant was to go all over the linked-list before trying to get different input.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I removed the 2nd analysisString = input.next().trim(), but now it prints the validation error for as many elements in the List since the error message is within the for loop. But, I'm closer than I was before!